# How do I keep whenever/capistrano from overwriting jobs for other environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3, whenever, whenever-capistrano

I have two environments, `staging` and `production`, on one server, being deployed with capistrano 3. The deploys for each environment clobber each other, fully replacing the other environment's jobs.

- If I deploy `staging`, then all of the cronjobs are removed and replaced with jobs referencing the `staging` release path and environment. All of the `production` jobs are removed.
- If I deploy `production`, then all of the cronjobs are removed and replaced with jobs referencing the `production` release path and environment. All of the `staging` jobs are removed.
- If I do a `case` statement in `schedule.rb` on `@environment`, and only have jobs set for a `when 'production'` situation, then when `staging` is deployed it completely clears the cronjobs. All of the jobs are gone.

I need to get to either of these two situations:

- Have two sets of jobs (one for `staging` and one for `production`) that each persist through either environment's deploy (so, in my example at the bottom, there would be two jobs listed - one for the `staging` release and one for the `production` release)
- One set of jobs (just for `production`) that persists through either environment's deploy (so, the `staging` deploy should not remove it)

Can anyone explain how this is done?
I've included my current configuration, below, in case it's helpful.

**Versions**

- capistrano: 3.3.5
- whenever: 0.9.4
- ruby: 2.1.5
- rails: 3.2.21

**Capfile**

```
require 'whenever/capistrano'
```

**Relevant line in config/deploy/deploy.rb**

```
set :application, 'application_name'
```

**config/deploy/production.rb**

```
server '1.2.3.4', user: 'username', roles: %w{web app}
set :branch, 'master'
set :deploy_to, '/home/username/production'
set :rails_env, 'production'
set :stage, :production
set :whenever_environment, -> { fetch(:stage) }
set :whenever_identifier, -> { "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}" }
```

**config/deploy/staging.rb**

```
server '1.2.3.4', user: 'username', roles: %w{web app}
set :branch, 'staging'
set :deploy_to, '/home/username/staging'
set :rails_env, 'staging'
set :stage, :staging
set :whenever_environment, -> { fetch(:stage) }
set :whenever_identifier, -> { "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}" }
```

**config/schedule.rb**

```
set :output, '/log/cron.log'
every 10.minutes do
  runner 'ModelName.method_name'
end
```

**The resulting cronjob after a `staging` deploy**

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: application_name
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/username/staging/releases/20150317012814 && script/rails runner -e staging '\''ModelName.method_name'\'' >> /log/cron.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: application_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any comment blocks surrounding the actual cron jobs?  I have an old Rails 3 app that uses this (and just this) and it works.  Maybe it will help:

```
config/deploy.rb:set :whenever_environment, defer { stage }
config/deploy.rb:set :whenever_identifier, defer { "#{application}_#{stage}" }
config/deploy.rb:set :whenever_command, 'bundle exec whenever'
```

Comment: Oh, that question seems like it could be helpful! whenever seems to be using the `:application` value instead of the `:whenever_identifier` value. I've updated my question with info from the `deploy.rb` file and the surrounding comments in crontab.